# Benefit of local index in AWS DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

In DynamoDB I have a table like below example data

```
pk        sk                         name         price 
=======================================================
product   cat#phone#name#iPhone11    iPhone 11    500
product   cat#phone#name#Nokia1100   Nokia 1100   100
product   cat#phone#name#iPhone11    iPhone 11    500
```

In a case I have to search by name. So, first I have created a global index for name where in `index pk = pk, sk=name` . Then I made a search which working fine.

Now I have changed my decision and created a `local index for name`, where `name is sk`. It's also working fine. My question is if I use local index here, has there any benefit ? and when I should not use local index ? If global index not required here but I have used , has there any performance issues ?

Comment: It may be more beneficial to reference this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381744/difference-between-local-and-global-indexes-in-dynamodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@niloy-rony,

This AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html) very well explains LSI and GSI in detail.

Now to answer your questions
- LSI comes at no extra cost. You don't need to pay for GSI's RCUs, WCUs however need to pay for storage as depicted here in another AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html).
- One should not use LSI if you are very certain that single partition (ie - pk) of your main table (pk remains the same in LSI) can be over 10GB. This is also discussed in link shared above.
- There is no performance issue with LSI and GSI in terms of query latencies. However, reads in GSI are eventual consistent whereas LSI supports strong consistent reads.

---

Edit, putting excerpt from the AWS [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) to understand strong and eventual consistent reads.

**Strongly Consistent Reads** - When you request a strongly consistent read, DynamoDB returns a response with the most up-to-date data, reflecting the updates from all prior write operations that were successful.

**Eventually Consistent Reads** - When you read data from a DynamoDB table, the response might not reflect the results of a recently completed write operation. The response might include some stale data. If you repeat your read request after a short time, the response should return the latest data.

Refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-replica.html) AWS doc for tips to minimise propagation delay of data from main table to GSIs

Comment: Would you please explain more about "reads in GSI are eventual consistent whereas LSI supports strong consistent reads." ?

Comment: LSI acts like a new table for you, whereas GSI is an index over your main table and data might not be consistent between main table and GSI. Have updated answer for more details.